# Web Api Rest returns a Json with data but in Postman don't

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating a WebApi .net 4.6 in the debug mode shows me there are data:

[image: debug mode]
**Update** There's something wrong if the field "ClaseTipoDia" is null? When I see the result in postman returns and empty json

[image]

this is my object class...

```
     public class CurvaTipicaTO
{

    public string FrtID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Periodo { get; set; }

    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    public string TipoDia { get; set; }

    public double Periodo01 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo02 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo03 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo04 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo05 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo06 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo07 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo08 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo09 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo10 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo11 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo12 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo13 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo14 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo15 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo16 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo17 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo18 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo19 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo20 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo21 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo22 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo23 { get; set; }

    public double Periodo24 { get; set; }

    public string ClaseTipoDia { get; set; }

}
```

Do I need to convert my list to array or something else?
this is my controller logic the specific method

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult ConsultaTipicaPorTipoDia([FromBody] List<FiltroFronteraTO> lstFiltroFrontera, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)
        {
            XMlog.Info("Ingreso metodo Consulta Curva Tipica");
            try
            {

                if ((lstFiltroFrontera != null) && (lstFiltroFrontera.Count> 0))
                {
                    DGPRepository dGPRepository = new DGPRepository();
                    var result =   dGPRepository.ConsultaCurvaTipicaPorTipoDia(lstFiltroFrontera, fecha);

                    return Ok(result); 

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentNullException("lstFronteras es Null");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XMlog.Error("Error Producido al ListarCurvaTipica por Tipo de Dia  ==> ", ex);
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your controller logic?

Comment: Include your method declaration if possible.

Comment: @Ellis yes I can! posted!

Comment: @Thecor method Included, sorry I miss post it

Comment: Is your CurvaTipica class serializable? Does it have both getters and setters and are it's properties public?

Comment: @RickyStam No is not Serializable but it's properties are public

Comment: Can you try using Newtonsoft to serialize the respone to json string before you return Ok and check if you get a value? If you get empty object then it means that you are having a serialization issue for sure and look that way for a solution

Comment: @RickyStam yes, I have the problem a serialization, this the line that i code var ra = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Simple the solution

add

using Newtonsoft.Json; to the class ** CurveTipicaTO ** that I need to have serialized

and decorate every atribute with:

[JsonProperty("Field namexxxx")]